# Why are my checkbox values always null when posting with Ajax to a Controller?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I am posting data to a controller in my ASP.NET Core application via an Ajax call.  The function does a couple of things, the first is that it grabs the value from an input box, the second is that it iterates over a div and grabs all the values of `checked` checkboxes and stores them in an array.

The problem is that when this data is sent to the controller, the checkboxes are always `null` and I was wondering what I have done wrong.

> The form is presented to the user in a bootstrap 4 modal and as such, certain elements need to use `.find()` to get their values, such as view name as you'll see below.

Here is my code, the first part is the function that triggers when the form is submitted by the user:

```
//On submit do the following.
$("#ModalFormAddCustomView").submit(function (e) {

    //Define an empty array for the checkbox values.
    var checkboxData = [];

    //Grab the name of the view from the input.
    var viewName = e.find($('#ViewName').val());
    
    //Look at the div containing all the checkboxes and grab the id of
    //only the ones that are checked.
    $('#columnListContent input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {            
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            checkboxData.push($(this).attr('id'));
        }
    });
    
    //Create an ajax call to post the data      
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Position/AddCustomView/',
        data: {
            //Post the viewname and the checkboxes
            viewname: viewName,
            checkboxes: checkboxData
        },   
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("success")
        },
        fail: function (data) {
            console.log("failed")
        }
    });
})
```

Here is the controller that receives that information.  `viewname` has the view name as passed in by the ajax call however, `checkboxes` is null.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddCustomView(string viewname, string checkboxes)
{
    ...rest of code would be here.
}
```

Here is a brief view of my form as well

```
<form id="ModalFormAddCustomView" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="AddCustomView" asp-controller="Position">
    <div class="md-form form-group">
        <label asp-for="ViewName">View Name</label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="ViewName" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="ColumnName" name="ColumnName">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="ColumnName">Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="ColumnDesign" name="ColumnDesign">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="ColumnDesign">Design</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Save</button>
</form>
```

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Look at the console. `e.find()` will be causing an error at least

Comment: Ignoring the above issue, the problem is because you're sending an array of strings in the request, not a single one. Change `string checkboxes` to `string[] checkboxes`. Also note that the JS code can be simplified using `:checkbox:checked` and `map()`: https://jsfiddle.net/7msgkc9e/1/.

Comment: Where is the element of ID: columnListContent

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <form id="ModalFormAddCustomView" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="AddCustomView" asp-controller="Position">
>     ....
>     <button type="submit" class="btn">Save</button>
> </form>
> ```

and

> ```
> $('#columnListContent input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {            
>     if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
>         checkboxData.push($(this).attr('id'));
>     }
> });
> ```

The issue is related to the JQuery selector value. According to the above code, I suppose you want to find the checkbox from the "ModalFormAddCustomView" form, but in the JQuery script, you are finding checkboxes from the "columnListContent" container. So, it can't find the checkbox and the value is null.

To solve this issue, try to change the JQuery code as below:

```
$('#ModalFormAddCustomView input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {            
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        checkboxData.push($(this).attr('id'));
    }
});
```